# Problem with relations beetwen entity models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

I want to make a Like and Dislike system in my project ,
I have a model for User, a model for Post, a model for Comment with relations below:

User 1 ---> * Post

User 1 ---> * Comment

Post 1 ---> * Comment

now I want to add a new model called Like with relations below:

Post 1 ---> * Like
User 1 ---> * Like

but when I want to update database I get an error that says :
"may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths"
I found out if I remove one of my properties it fix the error,
for example:

```
public class Post
{

    public Post()
    {

    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Like> Likes { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

}



public class Like
{

    public Like()
    {

    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public bool IsLike { get; set; }


    public int postId { get; set; } // I remove these properties

    public virtual Post post { get; set; }


    public int commentId { get; set; }  // I remove these properties

    public virtual Comment comment { get; set; }

}
```

for fixing the "multiple cascade" error I delete "PostId" and "commentId" properties .

But when I add entity (new data) to my table (Like) in database ,
I don't know some how my post gets duplicated I mean a repeat of post become added to the table.

can any body tell me the problem?

Comment: Check my updated answer. I have made some more changes.

Comment: You should show the code that duplicates the posts. I bet it's yet another instance of [this infamous pitfall](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Answer (score 0):

For better design, separate your like table for `Post` and `Comment` as follows:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //......

    public virtual List<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

    public virtual List<PostLikes> PostLikes { get; set; }

    public virtual List<CommentLIkes> CommentLikes { get; set; }
}


public class Post
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual List<PostLike> PostLikes { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string CommentBody { get; set; }

    //.....

    public virtual List<CommentLike> CommentLikes { get; set; }
}

public class PostLike
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int PostId { get; set; }

    public int UserId {get; set;}

    public bool IsLike { get; set; }

    public virtual Post post { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public class CommentLike
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int CommentId { get; set; }

    public int UserId {get; set;}

    public bool IsLike { get; set; }

    public virtual Comment Comment { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

}
```

Now generate a brand new Migration and update the database accordingly.

Note: you may face cascade delete problem on migration update. If you face let me know I shall update the answer with Fluent API configuration.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your response , but I didn't get reason of some of your code for example why you have repeated 'IsLike' Property in models ?
Wasn't it better if we had a seprate model for 'Like' ?

Comment: Yes! You can omit the `IsLike` property if you only have like option. If you have dislike option then keep this property to indicate that false means dislike.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that your database is not normalized enough.

I see that users can create `Posts`. They can also `Comment` on a `Post` and they can `Like` comments.

Because a `Comment` is a `Comment about a Post`, a `Like` on this `Comment` is automatically a `Like` on the `Post` that the comment is about

In other words: if someone created a comment (4) about Post (10), then it is ridiculous to create a Like for comment (4) and Post (20). comment (4) has nothing to do with post (20)!

Every Like is created by exactly one User about exactly one Comment. A user creates zero or more likes (one-to-many), and a comment has been liked zero or more times (also a one to many)

So you have the following sequence of actions:

- User 1 creates Post 10: Post 10 has foreign key CreateByUserId 1
- User 2 creates comment 20 about Post 10. Comment 20 has CommentedByUserId 2 and PostId 20
- User 3 likes comment 20. Like 30 has LikedByUserId 3 and CommentId 20

This is normalized enough for entity framework. To make the relations clearer I changed the foreign keys a bit.

```
class User
{
     public int Id {get; set;}
     ...

     // Every User creates zero or more Posts (one-to-many)
     public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts {get; set;}

     // Every User creates zero or more Comments (one-to-many)
     public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments {get; set;}

     // Every User creates zero or more Likes (one-to-many)
     public virtual ICollection<Like> Likes {get; set;}
}

class Post
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ...

    // Every Post is posted by exactly one User, using foreign key
    public int PostedByUserId {get; set;}
    public User User {get; set;}

    // Every Post has zero or more Comments (one-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments {get; set;}
}
```

And Classes Comment and Like:

```
class Comment
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ...

    // Every Comment is posted by exactly one User, using foreign key
    public int CommentedByUserId {get; set;}
    public virtual User User {get; set;}

    // Every Comment is about exactly one Post, using foreign key
    public int PostId {get; set;}
    public virtual Post Post {get; set;}

    // Every Comment has zero or more Likes (one-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<Like> Likes {get; set;}
}
class Like
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ...

    // Every Like is created by exactly one User, using foreign key
    public int LikedByUserId {get; set;}
    public virtual User User {get; set;}

    // Every Like is about exactly one Comment, using foreign key
    public int CommentId {get; set;}
    public virtual Comment Comment {get; set;}
}
```

Because my foreign keys deviate from the conventions I need to inform entity framework about these foreign keys using fluent API:

Post has foreign key to User:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
    .HasRequired(post => post.User)
    .WithMany(user => user.Posts)
    .HasForeignKey(post => post.CreatedByUserId);
```

Comment has foreign keys to User and Post:

```
var commentEntity = modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>();
commentEntity.HasRequired(comment => comment.User)
    .WithMany(user => user.Comments)
    .HasForeignKey(comment => comment.CommentedByUserId);
commentEntity.HasRequired(comment => comment.Post)
    .WithMany(post => post.Comments)
    .HasForeignKey(comment => comment.PostId);
```

Like has foreign keys to User and Comment:

```
var likeEntity = modelBuilder.Entity<Like>();
likeEntity.HasRequired(like => like.User)
    .WithMany(user => user.Likes)
    .HasForeignKey(like => like.LikedByUserId);
likeEntity.HasRequired(like  => like.Comment)
    .WithMany(comment => comment.Likes)
    .HasForeignKey(like => like.CommentId);
```

If in future you want to give the possibility to for users to Like a Post instead of a Comment, or maybe like a User, the relations will be very similar. Start by giving the User the proper `virtual ICollection<...>` (every User like zero or more ...), and you will automatically know where to put the foreign keys

Comment: I think you didn't get the point, I want users be able to like posts not comments.

Comment: In that case you have something very similar: a User has a collection of zero or more liked posts, and every post is liked by zero or more users. A like has a foreign key to the User who liked it and a foreign key to the post that was liked. I assumed you would figure that out yourself